# How to separate numbers from text using SPLIT/LEFT/RIGHT function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheets documents with data in this format:

`Some data 10:5 Somemore Data`

I am trying to separate the text from the numbers in separate columns based on the colon sign so that the output looks like this:

`Some data | 10 | 5 | Somemore Data`

I tried the SPLIT and RIGHT/LEFT functions but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have so far

```
=LEFT(C2,FIND(":",C2)-3)
```

This separates the text on the LEFT but using it on the right side doesn't work. My formula also doesn't separate the numbers. Looking for a formula that can achieve the above desired result.

My spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EmL4kzCGxRbwvNJntwMokqgt8yjjAqnZuUidTbZe6Z8/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a solution in your shared sheet with `SPLIT` and `REGEXREPLACE`.

Here is one a bit simpler with `REGEXEXTRACT`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="", "", REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"^(.+?)[  ]+(\d+)[  ]*:[  ]*(\d+)[  ]+(.+)$")))
```

Every group will be a cell in a row to the right.

Regex description and demo: [link](https://regex101.com/r/6KG35R/1).

**Edit:** stripped spaces. You have a nasty chars in your strings - nonbreaking space bar which is indistinguishable from the regular space. Could not understand why a simpler regex (`^(.+?)\s+(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s+(.+)$`) did not work. All because of this nbsp (char 160). Thus `[  ]` (nbsp and a regular space) instead of just `\s`.

[image]